# Why do Super User and Server Fault have "Meta" before their names?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, site-name

[image: Meta sites]

Other sites do not. Why is that? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Other than Super User, Server Fault, Stack Overflow also has **Meta** Stack Overflow.

These three sites are called as Trilogy, short form as SOFU. They are the initial creation of the sites. Reference: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/31/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/

After these three sites creation, the [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com) network was started. Later for the newly created site's meta  contains the **Meta** in the last, but they didn't change for it's trilogy sites.

Also the meta site URL of the trilogy sites are `https://meta.<sitename>.com`, whereas the remaining site's meta URL are `https://<sitename>.meta.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: This site is not in the trilogy, or should therefore be called "Stack Exchange Meta"

Comment: This is cool and all, but doesn't explain why the Meta has to be in front for those three sites. There is no logical connection between the two. The Meta was started much later than the so-called trilogy,  as well.

Comment: @ICanHazUpvotzPleez I think it's just an inertia, and it's just the cost is more than the benefit